# Access data in model from JavaScript in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My knowledge of ASP.NET is very limited and new, so please correct anything which I've failed to understand.

I'm current generating a collection of graphs using Google Charts, but each time I'm querying the database for the same set of data. I'd like to store this somewhere or only retrieve the data once to improve performance.

I looked into caching, but every time my script moved onto the next chart, the data was no longer in the cache. So my other idea was to get the data once, generate the JSON strings for all the charts, and store them in the model. Then I could get the data by going 'Model.chart1 - Model.chart2' etc.

However, I cannot seem to access this data from the Javascript in my view. I am able to get there from the html by placing the '@Model.chart1' inside a div container.

The desired behaviour would be to access this data from inside a JQuery function as shown below. But instead of calling the method from the controller, just directly access the model field like 'var chart1 = @Model.chartOne'

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartOne);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTwo);

    function drawChartOne() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/GetChartOne",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var options = {

            title: 'Chart One',

            hAxis: {
                title: 'Date'
            },

            vAxis: {
                title: 'Hours'
            },

            explorer: {
                keepInBounds: true
            },

            height: 500,
            width: 1000

        };

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ChartOne'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

    function drawChartTwo() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/GetChartTwo",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var options = {

            title: 'Chart Two',

            hAxis: {
                title: 'Date'
            },

            vAxis: {
                title: 'Hours'
            },

            explorer: {
                keepInBounds: true
            },

            height: 500,
            width: 1000

        };

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ChartTwo'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a little reading up and education about proper use of MVC.

I ended up creating a base model class called "Graph", and then another two models for GraphOne and GraphTwo, both inheriting from Graph.

I then created a ViewModel which stored a list of type Graph. This meant I could store all my different graphs in one list to access from within the JavaScript.

From the controller, on request, I could then load up the data once, and then pass the data to each GraphOne and GraphTwo to do their respective processing. Importantly, only loading the data once. I then returned the ViewModel as an ActionResult, and could then access the properties I needed using strongly typed data types from within the .cshtml class.

Probably a very poor explanation, but hopefully it will help someone. I had a bit of a hard time finding a decent tutorial on ASP MVC. Here is a very good series I followed and would recommend:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-step-by-step-in-days-Day